# How to read ip camera(rtsp) frames with python?

Tags: python, video, video-processing, rtsp, ip-camera

i want to read frames from streaming videos(ip camera).
i already tried "cv2.videocapture" (opencv-python) , but it occured errors.

[image]

is there any method to read frames?

Answer (score -1):

You can use this [rtsp client](https://pypi.org/project/rtsp/). It's available on PyPi. You should atleast google your requirement first before posting your question here.

Check out this [StackOverflow guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to best ask questions.